# FileNotFoundException using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, filenotfoundexception

im new with Android Studio, and I want to connect Android Studio, to a database created in another compiler. When I execute the debugger and reach de line "BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));", I get and Exception call "FileNotFoundException".

Can someone help me?

Thank you very much.

public class Menu_Login extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText usuario, password;
Button login;
String url_login;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_login);
    usuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.escribir_nombre); // COMO DECLARAR UN EDIT TEXT
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.escribir_contraseña);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click_boton);
    final Context context = this;
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String user = usuario.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
            url_login = String.format("http://192.168.1.35/loguear?nombre=%s&password=%s",user,pass);
            new MultiplyTask(context).execute(user);

        }
    });
}
public class MultiplyTask extends AsyncTask <String,Void,String>
{
    Context context;
    private MultiplyTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String value) {
        TextView n = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.mostrar_resultado);
        n.setText(value);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(url_login);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 );
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            int status = conn.getResponseCode();
            InputStream error = conn.getErrorStream();
            String value = bf.readLine();
            return value;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I also added  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: `a database created in another compiler. ` ?? What would that be?

Comment: `I want to connect Android Studio, to ...` ??? Your code is connection your app with a http server.

Comment: Where is your app running? Emulator or real device?

Comment: `String value = bf.readLine();`. Why do you read only one line?

Comment: Please post the complete exception message.

Comment: I created a database in IntelliJ, and i want to acces this database with android Studio. 

I only read one line, because i know that i will only recieve one line.

Comment: I run my app in a real device.

Comment: You want to access a database with Android Studio? How would you do that? Where? I think you want to access a database with your Android app.

Comment: is url_login correct?

Comment: Please react to what i said. Be serious.

Comment: Yes greenapps. That's why i'm trying to say sorry.

Comment: @adityua1508 it is. I put in on the browser and it works